# label of the resistors using circuitkz

Tags: labels, circuitikz

How can I put the label of the resistors horizontally instead of being in the same direction of the component?

I tried to use `[R, l=$R_c$:-90]` as an example I saw but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}                           % for flowcharts
\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
            \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
            \draw (0,0) 
            to[R, l=$R_c$, o-o] (4,0)
            to[R, l=$R_a$, o-o] (2,-3)
            to[R, l=$R_b$, o-o] (0,0)
            {[anchor=east] (0,0) node {a} [anchor=west] (4,0) node {b} [anchor = north] (2,-3) node {c}};
            \end{circuitikz}
            $\hspace{0.25in} \displaystyle \Leftrightarrow \hspace{0.25in}$
            \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
            \draw (0,0) 
            to[R, l=$R_1$, o-*] (2,-1)
            to[R, l=$R_2$, *-o] (4,0) (2,-1)
            to[R, l=$R_3$, *-o] (2,-3)
            {[anchor=east] (0,0) node {a} [anchor=west] (4,0) node {b} [anchor = north] (2,-3) node {c}};
            \end{circuitikz}
            \end{center}
\end{document}
```

This is how it is

[image]

This is what I would like

[image]

PS: I would like also to put the arrow between the two images more centralized. Is that possible?

Best regards!

Comment: `\ctikzset {label/align = straight}` or `\usepackage[straightlabels]{circuitikz}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight labeling can be achieved with the `\ctikzset` macro:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
    \ctikzset { label/align = straight }
    \draw (0,0)
    to[R, l=$R_c$, o-o] (4,0) % The voltage source
    to[R, l=$R_a$, o-o] (2,-3)
    to[R, l=$R_b$, o-o] (0,0)
    {[anchor=east] (0,0) node {a} [anchor=west] (4,0) node {b} [anchor = north] (2,-3) node {c}};
  \end{circuitikz}
  $\hspace{0.25in} \displaystyle \Leftrightarrow \hspace{0.25in}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This, and other information on circuitikz labeling can be found on p. 25 of the [circuitikz official documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf).